# Laravel default locale not in url

Tags: laravel, routes, localization, locale

Suppose I have 3 (or more languages) on site. English, Italian, French. English being the default.

I want the homepage url to be:

- mysite.com/ - for english
- mysite.com/it - for italian
- mysite.com/fr - for french

My route is currently

```
Route::get('/{locale}', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

This works for French, Italian but obviously not for English being just mysite.com/

I dont want another route like

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')
```

Because then I wouldn be able to simply call home in any language as

```
{{ route('home', $locale) }}
```

Whats the best solution?

Comment: Write an `if` statement to check `$locale` in `routes and redirect to your home route?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of my old solutions but still should work:
In the beginning of routes.php

```
$locale = Request::segment(1);

if(in_array($locale, ['en','fr','it'])){
    app()->setLocale($locale);
}else{
    app()->setLocale('en');

    $locale = '';
}
```

Then

```
Route::group([
  'prefix' => $locale
], function(){ 
   Route::get('/demo', 'TestController@demo')->name('demo');
   ...
})
```

**Important:** You should always use named routes in this scenario. The generated URLs will then be for the current locale:

`route('demo')` will return `/demo` when app locale is english, and `/it/demo` when app locale is italian!

Answer (score 2):

Laravel allows optional parameters in route definition, so you can set `local` route parameter as optional for your usage :

```
Route::get('/{locale?}', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

And in your **HomeController**, check the parameter to know if locale is present

```
public function index(Request $request, $locale = null) {
  if (empty($locale)) {
    $locale = 'en'; // english by default
  }

  ...
}
```

Hope it's helps you :)

Comment: this is quite nice solution. What would you do for other pages. I suppose you cannot do something like: Route::get('/{locale?}/my-page', 'HomeController@my-page')->name('my-page');

Comment: No. Optional parameters need to go to the end of the route, otherwise Router wouldn't know how to match URLs to routes