# How to make locale optional in Laravel routing?

Tags: laravel, routes, locale

Hope you are doing well. I am stuck with Laravel routing issue. My main purpose is to make routes with optional `{locale?}` parameter.
Basically, I have multiple versions of my website. Version means languages. Blogs are uploaded in different languages. So, I want routes to be like this

```
domain.com/
```

this would be general route and language should be english that i don't want to show in URL. In this case my all other blogs URLs Would be like this

```
https://example.com/{category}/{any-blog-slug}
```

And for the other languages i want routes to be like

```
example.com/arabic
example.com/french
example.com/german
```

and  blogs URLs i want to be like this

```
https://example.com/{locale}/{category}/{any-blog-slug}
```

Please have a look on my web.php routes

```
Route::group(["prefix"=>"{locale?}",'middleware'=>'getLang'],function(){

    Route::get('/',[WebsiteController::class,'get_homepage'])->name('homepage');
    Route::get('{category}',[WebsiteController::class,'category_all_news'])->name('category_all_news')->middleware('getLang');
    Route::get('{category}/{slug}',[WebsiteController::class,'get_a_news_blog'])->name('get_a_news_blog')->middleware('getLang');
    
});
```

here is middleware

```
  $lang=$request->segment(1);
    // dd($lang);
    if((in_array($lang,Language::where('language','!=','english')->pluck('language')->toArray())) || !$lang){
        app()->setLocale($lang);
    }


     $request->route()->forgetParameter('locale');
    
     URL::defaults(['locale' => app()->getLocale()]);
    
     return $next($request);
```

issue is that when i click on any category, the category is considered as locale.

How can i solve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess, your middleware should be added on the route with local parameter only, then for those that doesnt have locale, it should be defaulted to en

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel - locale optionally as first parameter in the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57970465/laravel-locale-optionally-as-first-parameter-in-the-url)

Comment: also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50023513/laravel-default-locale-not-in-url

Comment: if there is no locale in the url, you can add a locale in the route and then redirect to new route. Thus you will always have locale.